# SQL query script to delete duplicates

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

Given is the sql script that deletes duplicates from the given table.
Table has three fields:

```
id (pk, int identity), imei (varchar), name (varchar), lastconnected (datetime)
```

Some of the records in this table have the same value for name and imei, but with diffrent value for id and lastconnected.Mentioned sql script deletes the duplicate records except the one record with latest value for lastconnected.

The problem arising here is that this script deletes everything that is not a duplicate like entry with id 10 is deleted as well.

How to solve this issue ?

```
DECLARE @table TABLE
(
  id int, 
  name varchar(10),
  imei varchar(10),
  [date] datetime
)

insert into @table select 1, 'a','a', '2015/01/01' 
insert into @table select 2, 'a','a', '2016/01/01' 
insert into @table select 3, 'a','a', '2017/02/01'
insert into @table select 4, 'b','b', '2017/01/01' 
insert into @table select 5, 'b','b', '2016/01/01' 
insert into @table select 6, 'c','c', '2017/01/03' 
insert into @table select 7, 'c','c', '2016/01/01' 
insert into @table select 8, 'd','d', '2017/05/05' 
insert into @table select 9, 'd','d', '2016/01/01' 
insert into @table select 10, 'e','e', '2016/01/01'

WHILE (exists (select IMEI, COUNT(IMEI) from @table group by IMEI having    COUNT(IMEI) > 1))  
BEGIN  
 delete from @table where [date]  in (
 select min([date]) from @table group by imei , name having count(*) > 1)   
End 

select * from @table
```

Comment: add desired output pls

Comment: What version of SQL Server? Seems like an ideal use for windowing functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this:

```
DECLARE @table TABLE
(
  id int, 
  name varchar(10),
  imei varchar(10),
  [date] datetime
)

insert into @table select 1, 'a','a', '2015/01/01' 
insert into @table select 2, 'a','a', '2016/01/01' 
insert into @table select 3, 'a','a', '2017/02/01'
insert into @table select 4, 'b','b', '2017/01/01' 
insert into @table select 5, 'b','b', '2016/01/01' 
insert into @table select 6, 'c','c', '2017/01/03' 
insert into @table select 7, 'c','c', '2016/01/01' 
insert into @table select 8, 'd','d', '2017/05/05' 
insert into @table select 9, 'd','d', '2016/01/01' 
insert into @table select 10, 'e','e', '2016/01/01'

;WITH cte AS(
  select *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY imei ORDER BY date DESC) rn
    from @table
)
DELETE FROM cte
  WHERE rn > 1

SELECT * FROM @table
```

Comment: It works! But can you please explain the 'over', 'partition by' and 'with' keyword. I have never seen them before.

Comment: "WITH" intiates a common table expression. It could be replaced by a subquery - however, I prefer the cte since it makes the code a bit more readable. ROW_NUMBER() OVER... defines how the row number has to be provided: PARTITION BY imei means numbering of each rows with the same imei, ORDER BY date DESC gives the order of the numbering. In your example: the newest date of imei "a" received rownumber 1, the next date rownumber 2 and so on. Then repeat for imei b: the newest receives rownumber 1 and so on and so on... hope this is clear?

Comment: as mentioned by @Cool_Br33ze, you defined the duplicates by imei AND name, so you might want to extend the "PARTITION BY imei" to "PARTITION BY imei, name"... but honestly I guess imei itself should be unique... but I might be mistaken.

Comment: yes the imei is unique. your example will work perfectly. Thank you very much for your answer and the following explanation of the keywords!

Comment: so now i want to do this in the real table with important data. If i delete these dublicates. Is there anyways to get them back with some kind of rollback or something?

Comment: If you perform the delete within a transaction, you can roll it back, yes. But maybe it would better suit your requirements to store them away? e.g. use the same statement and replace the DELETE section by a "SELECT * INTO my_dup_backup FROM cte WHERE rn > 1". This should create a new table with your duplicates. Afterwards check this new table if it's complete. Last but not least, perform the delete.

Comment: okey i understand. One last thing. How can i acces/see this my_dup_backup. What is it? does it automatically create a table that i can acces via object explorer. Is it a temporary table like cte?

Comment: "SELECT...INTO..." Creates a real physical table.

Answer (score 0):

Simple `EXISTS` way:

```
delete from tablename t1
where exists (select 1 from tablename t2
              where t2.imei = t1.imei 
                and t2.name = t1.name
                and t2.lastconnected > t1.lastconnected )
```

Delete a row if there exists another row with same imei and name but later lastconnected.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved easily with a Common Table Expression (CTE) and a ROW_Number function

```
;WITH cteDups
AS(
    SELECT
          T.name
        , T.imei
        , T.date
        , RN = ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY T.name, T.imei ORDER BY T.date DESC)
    FROM @table T
)
--SELECT * FROM cteDups D WHERE D.RN > 1
DELETE FROM cteDups WHERE RN > 1
```

Comment: Yep, same solution as I proposed a bit further down. :-)

Comment: @Tyon78 Oh yeah , :-) But the OP mentioned the duplicate was on Name and IMEI

Answer (score 0):

You have a primary key so the query can be very simple without using CTE:

```
DECLARE @table TABLE
(
  id int, 
  name varchar(10),
  imei varchar(10),
  [date] datetime
)

insert into @table select 1, 'a','a', '2015/01/01' 
insert into @table select 2, 'a','a', '2016/01/01' 
insert into @table select 3, 'a','a', '2017/02/01'
insert into @table select 4, 'b','b', '2017/01/01' 
insert into @table select 5, 'b','b', '2016/01/01' 
insert into @table select 6, 'c','c', '2017/01/03' 
insert into @table select 7, 'c','c', '2016/01/01' 
insert into @table select 8, 'd','d', '2017/05/05' 
insert into @table select 9, 'd','d', '2016/01/01' 
insert into @table select 10, 'e','e', '2016/01/01'

DELETE t1
FROM @table t
    JOIN @table t1 ON t1.name = t.name AND t1.imei = t.imei
WHERE t1.id < t.id

SELECT * FROM @table
```